# Entity Framework class with list of object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF 6.0 and ASP.NET MVC with C# and I have two classes - `project` and `feature`:

```
public class project
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string aliasName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<feature> features { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class feature
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

The end-user will pick more than one feature per project, and each project can contain different features.

How can I setup this in EF and store this selection in db?

In `dbContext` I have at this moment:

```
public DbSet<project> Projects { get; set; }
public DbSet<feature> Features { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 7):

Right now, you are trying to store the entire list of "Features" into the "Project" database when all you need to store is a unique identifier for each "Feature" which is the Feature.id property. So "Project" could be:

```
public class project
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string aliasName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Features")]
    public virtual List<int> featureIds { get; set; }
}
```

When you need specific Feature data, just query the Feature database for the specific feature id. [Here is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) more information about using foreign keys within Entity.

Comment: And how I can save this relationship list into db? Should I add something to my dbcontext?

Comment: Are you creating a new db to store this or trying to update an old one. If you haven't made the database yet, you shouldn't need to add anything. Otherwise, you might need to [migrate the database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx#Enabling%20Migrations).

Comment: The db is a new one. When I build there is no table that links featuresIds with projectId, only Projects and Features tables.

Comment: You should only have those two tables since those house all of the data you need. The featureids just hold a list of ids located in the Features table. For example if Project has two features, feature id will include the feature with id = 1 and id = 2. If you need to know what are the properties of those features, you just query the Feature table for Feature.id =1 and Feature.id = 2.

Comment: But Entity Framework should create a table with projectId and featureId columns no? If each project contains multiple features associate (different projects could share same features) I need to store this info somewhere. The features table is just a repository of template features.

Answer (score 6):

In Project class:

```
public virtual ICollection<feature> feature { get; set; }
```

And in dbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<project>().HasMany(i => i.feature).WithMany();
```